# I need to download a PDF by url

Tags: javascript, pdf, download

I have read some posts about the same, but I haven't been able to solve my problem.

I only get the pdf on the same tab I was navigating, which I don't want. I need the pdf to start downloading on the explorer but I am quite lost about what should be my next step. I also need to give the pdf some params to print it, but this is a topic I will be able to do debugging. This is my code, which is called from a button on the HTML.

```
downloadPDF(){
    let vm = this;
    let pdf = this.URL_ANEXO_;
    let blob = new Blob([pdf], { type: 'data:attachment/pdf;charset=utf-8' });

    let fileName = 'ANEXO_.pdf';;

    let link: any = document.createElement('a');

    let url = this.URL_ANEX_;
    link.href = url;
    link.download = fileName;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();

    setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.removeChild(link);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 100);


        }

}
```